# 5v ac output to a 5vdc input ?? does that work or not

Tags: usb

I have a charger for an e cig and it came with a charger with a usb cable but no wall plug. I have a couple wall plugs that are mostly the same. I have a wall plug with a usb port for the charger usb wire to plug into, the charger says DC5v input. The wall plug usb port part is an ac adapter output 5v ac. Will that not work and blow up?

Comment: No, AC output will not work for something that needs DC input.

Comment: Connecting it could also damage the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of an AC adapter that outputs 5V AC but has a USB plug on it of any style.

But as was mentioned by the previous poster, in just about all cases, devices needing DC power absolutely will not run on AC. There's a couple of extremely rare exceptions - for example, LED lamps which run on DC can run on AC but will flicker at the speed of the AC wave (in the US, 60 times per second).

If the E-cig came with a cable that has a USB plug on the end, you should be able to plug it into just about any USB port you come across. There's also tons of sources for wall-outlet-to-USB chargers.

Comment: Older linksys routers used 5v ac power bricks.